# Informix—performance timer always zero

Tags: informix

I’m trying to set up a performance timer in some Informix sprocs to see how long an insert is taking. I think I’m close, but I’m getting all zeros back. I'm using the code below in the real sprocs, too, which contain real insert statements (i.e., not just the sleep statement). It still returns all zeroes. It should be at least a few milliseconds, I would think. Anything jump out that I’m doing wrong?

EDIT: I also tried using `sysdate` instead of `current` and still got all zeroes.

Return value in C#: 0.00000

Test sproc:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE JayTest() returning char(10);

     define start datetime second to fraction(5);
     define end datetime second to fraction(5);

     let start = current;

     system "sleep 1"; -- stuff happens here that I want to time

     let end = current;

     return ((end - start)::interval second to fraction(5))::char(10);

END PROCEDURE;
```

Answer (score 2):

It is the expected behavior according to the documentation (Informix 12.10):

> SQL is not a procedural language, and CURRENT might not execute in the lexical order of its position in a statement. You should not use
>   CURRENT to mark the start, the end, nor a specific point in the
>   execution of an SQL statement.
>
> If you use the CURRENT operator in more than once in a single
>   statement, identical values might be returned by each instance of
>   CURRENT. You cannot rely on CURRENT to return distinct values each
>   time it executes.
>
> The returned value is based on the system clock and is fixed when the
>   SQL statement that specifies CURRENT starts execution. For example,
>   any call to CURRENT from inside the SPL function that an EXECUTE
>   FUNCTION (or EXECUTE PROCEDURE) statement invokes returns the value of
>   the system clock when the SPL function starts.

[CURRENT Operator](https://www.ibm.com/support/knowledgecenter/en/SSGU8G_12.1.0/com.ibm.sqls.doc/ids_sqs_1455.htm)

If it is acceptable to do the time keeping arithmetic with a 2nd process and ignoring the overheads, a possible solution could be something like this:

```
SELECT SYSDATE AS start FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1;
PROCEDURE JayTest();
SELECT SYSDATE AS end FROM systables WHERE tabid = 1;
```

There is also the use of the column `sh_curtime` from the table `sysshmvals`in the `sysmaster` database as described in

[How to obtain the actual date and time in a stored procedure](http://www-01.ibm.com/support/docview.wss?uid=swg21252128)

The column contains the actual system time but it only has a precision up to the second, so useless if we want intervals up to fractions of a second.

Answer (score 1):

That's normal.  Time is frozen for the duration of a stored procedure — CURRENT will be reported the same throughout the execution, even if you run `SYSTEM('sleep 100');` in the middle of the procedure.

There isn't an easy workaround for this that I know of.